# Can the internal micro processor / electronics in a keyboard break?

Tags: usb, keyboard, hardware-failure, ps2

When I tried to connect my USB keyboard to another PC without USB, I used a USB to PS/2 converter but accidentally used the green connector, which is meant for mouses. So, my keyboard stopped working.

Does the keyboard have an internal micro processor or other electronic stuff that can break?

My keyboard doesn't even work anymore on my main PC.
When I plug it into USB, all LED light turn green...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Does the keyboard have an internal micro processor or other electronic stuff that can break?*

The answer is definitely yes. As opposed to some old style keyboards used in old home/personal computers, which were a passive switch matrix polled and decoded by the CPU, the PC keyboard is an active device. BTW, this is why it was possible to reprogram and tweak the old keyboards while it is harder in the PC world.

Whether it should be damaged by connecting to a mouse port - I don't think it should be harmful, but defective hardware is a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

PS/2 connectors are *usually* interchangeable, although adapters made by different manufacturers don't always work with all hardware. I haven't heard of one being responsible for shorting out hardware unless you were trying to plug/unplug while the PC was on.

Try rebooting your main PC. It's possible that there was a glitch with USB detection if you tried hot swapping it too quickly.